# Use of static to return a parent variable

Tags: php

My database connection is in a parent class called Model.

I am designing a utility class that I won't ever have an instance of so am using the static keyword. I only want access to the functions themselves around my application.

```
class Model {

    function __construct() {
        $this->db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
    }

}
```

This is my parent class.

```
class Fav extends Model{

    public static function getFavourite($data){
        return $this->db->select('SELECT favouriteid FROM favourite WHERE type = :type AND linkid = :linkid 
                              AND userid = :userid', array('type' => $data['type'], 'linkid' => $data['linkid'],
                              'userid' => Session::get('userid')));
    }
}
```

I'm having a problem with $this keyword as I don't have an instance of the class?

I know of the parent and self keywords.

Can someone resolve this and show me how I would associate the correct keyword here!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can pass `$db` as a parameter to the static method. Also try to find out the debate on _evilness_ of static methods on SO

Comment: Seems there are a vast majority who aren't keen on static methods!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from the fact that this doesn't look like real solid code, you could expand your base class with something like this:

```
protected static function getDatabase()
{
    return new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);
}
```

You can now use your database class by calling `self::getDatabase()->select("x");`

On an aside: be sure you want to do this with static functions. I wouldn't do it this way.

Comment: I want the best possible solution to this so if you believe this could be achieved in a better manner, could you give a suggestion?

Comment: That would be well out of the scope of this question. Your logic is tightly coupled and has hierarchy I wouldn't go for in the first place. Read about object oriented design concepts and keep trying to get to cleaner ways of programming things. ;)

Comment: That's cool, I appreciate the response. It's all a learning curve anyway! For every system I develop, the hierarchy improves. I'll bear this in mind for the next application I develop.

Answer (score 2):

You're making a few design flaws here.

1. You give your model knowledge about the database. Make something manage your models and than "push/flush" it to your database.
2. Fav::getFavourite() might seem nice in your code, but it doesn't make sense. You shouldn't be asking your model to retrieve itself.

I suggest you to take a look at existing ORM such as Doctrine or Propel and see how they solved design issues you're having.

edit:
A solution I would use for Symfony2:

```php
// I will have this registered under mybundle.favourites as service
class FavouritesService
{
  private $em;

  public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
  {
    $this->em = $em;
  }

  public function getFavourite($what, SomeUserObject $for)
  {
    // do some stuff with the manager here and retrieve my favourite.. based on $data
  }
}

// some random action in my controller
public function someAction()
{
  $favorite_car = $this->get('mybundle.favorites')->getFavourite('car', $this->get('session.user'));
  // some code
}
```

Comment: The model base class is designed to provide the database to all models I use for controllers. This works fine as those models extend the base model and it works well. In this instance, what I am looking to do is create a set of functions that will control the ability to favour an item on the site. So I just click a button and it goes and does something. I don't need any views/ controllers/ models for this, I just need a utility class that will provide the functionality. Does this seem like a problem that could be solved using static methods?

Comment: I'm not a fan of static. A) it blocks unittesting, B) it's nothing more than a "global" function wrapped in a class. It's totally against OO. In any case, the database doesn't need to know about models and the models not about the database. There's a layer between that which should know about both and use them right. That way you can unplug your database and replace it by something else or unplug your models and hook up some one else's system.

Comment: I have updated my answer to show you what I mean. This way you can for example mock an EntityManager to not actually save stuff in your database, makes testing easier and allows you to just get the FavouritesService in your code where you need it using Symfony2's Dependency Injection Container.

Comment: Ahhh I understand what you mean now. A layer in the middle, makes more sense! So this works for the Symfony2 framework? Is $this->get syntax for that framework in particular? It's the obvious way to get access to what I want in any controller, anywhere in my application!

Comment: In symfony2 you have a get() in your controller that's basically a shortcut for $this->getContainer()->get(); Your container holds many services that you can just insert. In this case you would create your service by adding a Doctrine EntityManager as parameter. Symfony internally will pass that as a construct parameter and you will have never have to worry about getting the EntityManager. 
Some very interesting reading material: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html

Answer (score -1):

In OOPS concept, static methods can only access static variables and methods, but PHP does not follow all OOPS concept. Basically, you should follow Singleton design pattern to get the database connection to make sure at a time only one object is initialized

```
class Model {
    public static $db;
    public static function getInstance () {
        if (!isset (self::$db))
             self::$db = new Database(DB_TYPE, DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        return self::$db;
    }
}
```

And you should use it as below

```
class Fav
{
     public static function getFavourite($data)
     {
        return Model::getInstance()->select('SELECT favouriteid FROM favourite WHERE type = :type AND linkid = :linkid 
                              AND userid = :userid', array('type' => $data['type'], 'linkid' => $data['linkid'],
                              'userid' => Session::get('userid')));
    }
}
```

No need to extend model class.

Comment: Your solution also makes the Model manage itself, bad solution.